# How to overwrite Ctest default timeout 1500 in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, timeout, ctest

My `CMakeLists.txt` includes the lines

```
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
set(CTEST_TEST_TIMEOUT 3)
add_test(...)
```

`ctest` works, but ignores my attempt to set the timeout. Rather, it runs with the default timeout of 1500.

How to change the default timeout? How is `CTEST_TEST_TIMEOUT` meant to be used?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`CTEST_TEST_TIMEOUT` is for use within the CTest script, not a `CMakeLists.txt` file. You can control the timeout in CMake for individual tests with the [`TIMEOUT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/TIMEOUT.html) test property, but there isn't a CMake variable that sets the global timeout default. The following sets the timeout to 30 seconds for just the `sometest` test:

```
add_test(sometest ...)
set_tests_properties(sometest PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 30)
```

You *can*, however, override the default timeout when you invoke `ctest` using the `--timeout` option. E.g. to run the tests with the global timeout default set to 120 seconds:

```
ctest --timeout 120
```

A timeout specified in CMake for an individual test still takes precedence over the globally set default timeout, even when the `--timeout` option is used.

Comment: "You can control the timeout in CMake for individual tests with the TIMEOUT test property" - how would I do this?

Comment: Is there a global setting for `CMakeLists.txt` files? Just like many other properties have global defaults, e.g `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` and `WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS`.

Comment: There's nothing you can put directly in a `CMakeLists.txt` file to control it. The `CTEST_TEST_TIMEOUT` variable can be put in a CTest dashboard script, but that's as close as you can get currently.